# DialogResult can be set only after Window is created and shown as dialog

Tags: c#, wpf, window, dialogresult

I have a main WPF window, mywindow.showDialog
when a button is clicked on the window, a command is executed 
let's say the command is SendToTableCommand

```
protected virtual void SendToTableExecute(object o)
{
    UIThread.BeginInvoke(new Action<object>(SendToTableExecuteUI),o);
}

private void SendToTableExecuteUI(object o)
{
    if (o is Control)
    {
        m_OwningWindow = UIHelper.FindVisualParent<Window>((Control)o);
    }

    do sth...

    if (m_OwningWindow != null)
    {
        //only set DialogResult when window is ShowDialog before
        if(System.Windows.Interop.ComponentDispatcher.IsThreadModal)
            m_OwningWindow.DialogResult = true;
    }
}
```

Sometime ago, `m_OwningWindow.DialogResult = true` throws exception. So I added an if check that uses IsThreadModal.  It has worked for a while, but now m_OwningWindowdoes not close because IsThreadModal is false.

I do not know what's the right way to solve the issue and think I did not handle it properly. 
Please help. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Jason's reply reminds me of a workaround. i.e. using Window.Close(), then add a bool type property on window, say OKClicked, replace anywhere that set DialogResult with window.Close(); window.OKClicked = true or false.  replace reference to window.DialogResult with window.OKClicked. 
Any problem with the workaround? thanks

Comment: my main concern is if it's safe to reference property of a window after window.close()?  there is no Disposed property on System.Windows.Window

Answer (score 0):

I was hiding my window before assigning `DialogResult`. Swapping the order, so `DialogResult` is assigned before the window is hidden, fixed my problem. Even if the window was `ShowDialog`'d, it must be considered "open" in order for `DialogResult` to be set.

**Edit**: And the window should be closed, not hidden. That bit me after I posted.

Answer (score -1):

Use `Form.Modal` to determine if your form is being opened as a window or a modal dialog.

You should be able to Close() the form when you want it to close, regardless of whether it's a dialog or not. (Under certain circumstances you may also need to Dispose it after closing)

Also, DialogResult is an enumerated type - `true` isn't a value I'd expect to see being assigned to it. Typically `DialogResult.OK` or `DialogResult.Yes` would be used for this.

Comment: thanks. It is not form. It is WPF window and there is no Modal property, I can use window.Close to close it but I want to do different things based on if users click OK button or Cancel to exit the window.  DialogResult on WPF window is bool? not enumerate